# Visio: How to unglue two shapes

Tags: microsoft-visio, shapes

I draw two shapes (say a line and an arc). Then I move the line so that one end of the line meets one end of the arc. As a consequence, the two shapes are glued together (because that is how I have set up Visio). And that is also what I usually want.

If I resize the arc in a later step, the connected end-point of the line moves (due to the gluing).

How can I unglue this automatic gluing, to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Does [Glue or unglue connectors](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/glue-or-unglue-connectors-c55370ae-a3c3-4468-9232-b32604f7252f) answer your question?

Comment: Hmmm, If I understand that information correctly then I would have to disable/enable the general setting. The seems to be no "manual" unglue.

Be aware that (at least to my understanding) Visio treats shapes and connectors differently. 
My question is pinpointed to shapes.

Answer (score 0):

In your particular case if you open the shapesheet for the line you will see that the BeginX/BeginY or EndX/EndY will contain a formula that relates to the shape it is glued to. It'll be something like:

=PAR(PNT(Sheet.2!Connections.X1,Sheet.2!Connections.Y1))

What needs to be done is to change the formula into an absolute value. If you right-click on the grey background you will see an option to show formulas or values, if you select values you can find the X/Y values where the line is located. All you have to do is replace the formula with the value, or a value very close by.